# Amazon EC2 t1.micro instance stops working occasionally

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

My t1.micro instance occasionally (once per month) stops working - can not to ssh and my web page is unavailable. I use LAMP. This is my test instance, so there is no a lot of traffic. I am the only user and I use it 5 days in month. 
Here is what happens with CPU when my instance stops

[image]

CPU normally is 2,3 and suddenly it loads to 99,7 (that is the point where apache stops - access.log is empty) for a while and after that CPU drops to 10,3 but apache do not recovers until I stop-start instance over again. I have no any error in apache logs. 
Any ideas why this is happens?

Comment: You're going to have to login to the server and see what process is using the CPU. I would recommend looking at the answers here for steps to monitor this issue: http://serverfault.com/questions/387268/linux-cpu-usage-and-process-execution-history

Comment: After a load spike like this, a t1 *will* become unresponsive.  The t2 class is much better -- it degrades much more gracefully and allows a lot more CPU before that's even possible.  The t1 should really not be used any more.

Comment: Thanks for comments guys. I follow CPU usage all the time, but all processes works fine - no processes which rises CPU more than 3%. I never spend CPU credit. That is why I am confused with behavior on this ec2 instance.